# Magento 2 PWA TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storeConfig')

Tags: magento2.4, pwa, pwa-studio, venia, yarn

We are using Magento 2.4.5

Steps to install PWA -

1 - git clone `https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git`

2 - Install yarn from pwa-studio root directory `yarn install`

3 - Create the .env file at location pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept\ using following command

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/" yarn buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept
```

4 - `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

5 - `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`

6 - Generate SSL Certificate using `yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept`

7 - `yarn run build`

then getting this error on command -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storeConfig')
    at /var/www/html/magento245/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:73:22
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async module.exports (/var/www/html/magento245/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/webpack.config.js:61:22)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/bin/node
Arguments: /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js run build
Directory: /var/www/html/magento245/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Sumeet Bajaj found any solution? If yes please guide me. I would appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Magento root directory and execute cmd below :

```
composer require magento/pwa

php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Magento_ContactGraphQlPwa

php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Magento_NewsletterGraphQlPwa

php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Magento_QuoteGraphQlPwa
```

After execute yarn command

Comment: @summet bajaj  check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

May this link solve your problem

https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/magento-2-cannot-find-field-newsletter_enabled-on-type-storeconfig-pwa-studio/

Run the below command in Magento root which is defined in the .env file of the PWA setup,
In my case, I used “MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL=https://example.com/” URL in the .env file, so I will run the below command from the “https://example.com/” Magento root directory.

Commands:-

composer require magento/pwa

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Then :

php bin/magento module:enable –clear-static-content Magento_ContactGraphQlPwa

php bin/magento module:enable –clear-static-content Magento_NewsletterGraphQlPwa

php bin/magento module:enable –clear-static-content Magento_QuoteGraphQlPwa